# Controller moving

Tags: ps4, controllers, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-ii

I am playing the new Call of Duty Modern Warfare 2. My controller + another controller is moving when I am aiming. What I mean is, when I aim and I move my controller it is also moving on the screen. Looks like we are playing with motion sensor.

But we only have controllers. Please can someone help with This?

Comment: apparently, PS4 controllers, called DS4 or Dual Shock 4 have built-in gyroscope... maybe take a look in game if there is an option to disable it? https://www.playstation.com/en-us/accessories/dualshock-4-wireless-controller/

Comment: Thanks we Found the probleme!!

Comment: just in case, post how you solved it as an answer, and you can accept your own answer as the solution